# How to fade out and close YUI div element

Tags: html, events, panel, yui

How can I close multiple instances of YUI div elements (modules) on one page. Following code is for one instance :

```js
YUI({filter: 'raw'}).use('node','anim', function(Y) {
   var anim = new Y.Anim({
    node: '#panel1',
    to: { opacity: 0 }
   });

   var onEnd = function() {
    var node = this.get('node');
    node.get('parentNode').removeChild(node);
   };

   anim.on('end', onEnd);

   Y.one('#panel1 .yui3-remove').on('click', anim.run, anim);


  });
```

```html
<div id="panel1" class="yui3-module">
 <div class="yui3-hd"><h3>Learners Progress</h3>  <a title="fade then remove element" class="yui3-remove"><em>x</em></a></div>
 <div class="yui3-bd" style="border:0px solid black" id="learnerStatus"></div>

</div>
```

How can I modify this code to use with multiple divs as this code takes id of the div. So, I have to replicate this for each div. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of different ways to achieve your goal and here is one of them: http://jsfiddle.net/2rw84usL/

HTML:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item">
        <h3>Learners Progress</h3>
        <span class="remove">Close</span>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <h3>Learners Progress</h3>
        <span class="remove">Close</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT:

```
YUI().use('node','anim', function(Y) {
    var anim = new Y.Anim({
        to: { opacity: 0 },
        duration: 0.5,
        on : {
            end : function() {
                var node = this.get('node');
                node.get('parentNode').removeChild(node);
            }
        }
    });

    Y.one('.items').delegate('click', function(e) {
        anim.set('node', e.target.get('parentNode')).run();
    }, '.remove');
});
```

Please note: I'm using event delegation here because this is more effective way to "listen" events from many similar elements (such as close buttons).

Read more about event delegation here: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/event/#delegation